# Expression cannot begin with "$\sum_{j=0}^{\floor*\frac{a}{b}} j$"

Tags: notebooks, syntax, summation, latex

[image]

This is my first time using Wolfram Mathematica and writing in TeX. I'm on the free trial version of Mathematica, and I'm writing in a notebook, using the "Inline TeX Input" option on the "Insert" tab. Previously, I have only ever written mathematics in MathJax.

I tried the above first without the dollar signs.
[image]

It didn't work then either. I figured maybe the problem was the lack of dollar signs. It appears not. A further confusing detail here is that the slash in front of the *sum* is red in the last picture, whereas it isn't in the one above. So I thought, maybe I have to add a dollar sign in front of all of them (not that that makes any sense to me, but I have no idea what I'm doing).
[image]

It still didn't work, but in this instance, the slashes aren't red anymore. I don't understand why this isn't working, according to [this guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), sigma functions are displayed by writing "\sum".

**EDIT:**

I tried doing as instructed in the answer by @Nasser, but upon pressing enter, the box turned red. Here's the code:

```
 Failure["TeXAssistantError", Association[
   "MessageTemplate" -> "Errors: `Errors`", 
   "MessageParameters" -> Association["Errors" -> {}], 
   "Input" -> "crtl$ \\sum_{j=0}^{3} j"]]
```

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you, I will do so :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first type `ctrl$` then type the LATEX there with no $'s, since it is implied math mode.  like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which was entered using

[image]

Then hit the return key.

For more info, see  [InlineTeXInput.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineTeXInput.html)

btw, no one really writes `*` in Latex as multiplication is implied with just the space. Better not use `*` in Latex.

Here is a video.  Hitting CTRL$ is just a short cut for using the menu. Both work the same.

[image]

Comment: I tried doing this, but it didn't work. I have edited my question to include my faulty code. Not sure how I did it wrong.

Comment: @user110391 Could you post the latex on its own in your question that you are trying to input? as plain text?  i.e. type the latex only. It could be your latex is not well formed.  do not use double backslash. Only ONE backslash. You type normal latex in the input windows. I just tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: Not sure what typing the latex as plain text means. Does it mean like this: "\sum_{j=0}^{3} j". That is the last expression I tried to put in, when I tried putting the "ctrl$" in front of it.

Comment: @user110391  You need to first type ctrl with dollar, then this should open a new small window like I showed. Only then you type the Latex there. are you using version 12.3?  If you like I can post a video showing how. But first you need to have that little new window open. You do NOT type ctrl with dollar inside the little window that opens up. Only pure latex goes there.

Comment: I'm using v. 12.3. This window does not appear when I type "ctrl$" in, but that window does show up when I choose "Inline TeX Input". If my further attempts are failed then a video would be nice yes :)

Comment: @user110391 OK, that will also work. Now just type the Latex there, in the small window that show up now, without that ctrl dollar. The ctrl dollar is just a short cut for `inline Tex Input` btw, you do not type ctrl with dollar, you need to press the keyboard keys CTRL$ at same time.

Comment: Using the "Inline TeX Input" was what I did to begin with, but it didn't work. The screenshots taken are from me writing LaTeX code in the window that appeared after pressing the "Inline TeX Input" option.

Comment: @user110391 I do not know why it is not working for you. Will add a small video.

Comment: What happened in the video happened for me as well, but **only** when I used the method of selecting "Inline TeX Input", it didn't work when I used the short cut "ctrl dollarsign". However, the process involving "Inline TeX Input" failed when using the other expression (the one featured at the top) $$\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \frac ab \rfloor} j$$ Also, how does one make mathematica solve the sigma function? The simple one with 3 as the max index value was displayed, but no output was given (i.e. the sum of sigma function).

Comment: @user110391 I just tried it. Mathematica does not understand the latex command \floor. Looks like a bug. This is all new stuff and will have bugs in it. So basically try not to use these commands in your Input Latex for now.  As for your sigma function solving, I suggest you make separate question on that, not related to Latex at all and keep it all using Mathematica code. Else this is getting confusing to have it all here with the latex issues involved.

Comment: I see, the issues lies with the floor function. Thanks :) I'll be accepting your answer now.  Maybe you could somehow include the fact that it was the floor function messing things up in your answer? Also, this issue with the "ctrl$" command, was that caused by me having a different version than you? Maybe the 12.3 version doesn't have this command?

Comment: @user110391  There was no actual error when using the \floor command, but it does not render correctly. it produce wrong output. As for ctrl dollar, to enter this, need to press the CTRL SHIFT 4  keys at same time. The dollar is on the 4 key on standard keyboard.

Comment: Aha, I see. I completely misunderstood. I thought "crtl dollarsign" was a command, which was supposed to be written "crtl$", not that I was supposed to press control, shift and the 4th key. It now works for me.